# Replication from solr 4.10.3 to solr 5.3

Tags: solr, replication

We've been running solr 4.10.3 in production for years with simple master/slave replication.  We're at a point where upgrading to 5.3 makes sense, but we're trying to do so in the easiest way possible.  The current setup looks like this:

```
4.1_master => 4.1_slave
```

That being said, does anyone know if it is possible to seed the 5.3 instance via replication from the slave?  Like, do the indexes differ and would it work to do chained replication like this:

```
4.1_master => 4.1_slave => 5.3_slave
```

If not, an anyone suggest good documentation for the 5.3 upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wrapping up the upgrade from 4.7 to 5.3. It's actually much easier than what you are doing.

Here is the easiest way:

1.Install in parallel on the same box. Create collection, etc...
2.Merge the schemas and the solrconfig. Open the new one and the old one side by side and copy stuff from the old one into the new one. There are some differences; so this is important. Make sure this works. 
3. Shutdown Solr 4, copy the indexes into the new Solr. 
4. Indexes should be picked up without an issue. But make sure this works. 
5. Do your environment specific stuff on the new instance, like set up replication and whatever. 
Volia!

I have nginx in front of Solr, so once the upgrade is complete I can just redirect nginx to the new solr cluster and there is a no downtime upgrade right there.

One thing I've been pondering about is how to upgrade the Lucene indexes. It looks like after an optimize they get the new Lucene version in the filename; however in Dev and Test I ended up doing a full reindex. If you have aliases set up for the collections it should be pretty easy too.

I wrote some python code to make this easier. Here is the documentation:
http://solrclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Reindexer.html